# How does Ruby compare strings?

Tags: ruby, string, comparison

maybe someone knows the technical answer to the following behaviour:

```
s = "hello world!"
s == s.upcase
# =>false, because "hello world!" != "HELLO WORLD!"
s == s.upcase!
#=>true, because s is changed before comparison?
```

Mathias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen in every language, think of it this way

```
AreEqual(s, s.upcase())

vs.

AreEqual(s, s.upcase!())
```

In both cases, the upcase(!) function *has* to be called before it can be passed to AreEqual, and in the `upcase!()` case, it actually *changes the value of s*. `upcase()` returns a *new* string with the uppercased version of s.

Comment: Hmm, right. I forgot == is a method, too. So the above behaviour makes sense. Thank you! :)

Comment: Even if the equality comparison weren't a method--even if it were an operator--it would still make sense. The explanation here is an analogy.

Comment: Equality is definitely a method in Ruby, try typing "foo".== "bar" into irb :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that.

`upcase!` returns either the upcased string or `nil` if no changes were made, so the result of that comparison will always be `false` after the first time. But it's a very bad idea to depend on side-effect semantics that way.